# Function that takes generic arguments and returns generic value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a function:

`const r = (array, function) => { some stuff }`

However `array` and `function` arguments can be **anything**, but array **must be typeof array** and function **must be typeof function**.

However, the `array` can be array of anything - `any[]` anf `function` can be anything `function(...r: any): any`.

How can I type that `r` function to accept generic `array` and `function` arguments, but the type definition has to be passed when calling it?

E.g. 
Im calling it somewhere in my app:

`r([1,2,3], (r) => r + 2)`

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for something like this: `const r = <T>(a:Array<T>, f:Function) => { return 'some stuff' };`

and used like this: `r<number>([1,3,4],()=>{})`?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Looks good

Answer (score 1):

This is my interpretation of what your're looking for

```js
type Fn<T> = (arg: T) => T
type R = <T>(array: T[], fn: Fn<T>) => T

const r: R = (array, fn) => { 
    //some stuff
}
```

I prefer to split the type declaration and its usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const r = <T>(array: T[], fn: (argument: T) => T) => { /* ... */}
```